# jQuery; Code not working in HTML Page but working in console

Tags: jquery, html

**Problem**
I am working on a school presentation but in  which I am replacing the .swf animations using jQuery but it doesn't work. If copy the same code over to my console, it works like a charm! Any help?

**My Code**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class='div-header'>
  <div class='div-header-title'>Courier Services</div>
</div>
  <div class='div-animation-frame'>
  <h2>A Project By</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Naqi</li>
    <li>Musa</li>
    <li>Husnain</li>
    <li>Nafey</li>
    <li>Saeed</li>
    <li>Hanzala</li>
  </ul>
  <button class='button-start'>START</button>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var companiesList = ['tcs', 'ocs', 'dhl', 'leopards'];
 var currentIndex = 0;

$('.button-start').on('click', function() {
  $('body').append("<div class='div-next-fab'></div>");
  $('.div-next-fab').append("<i class='fas fa-arrow-right'>");
  $('.div-animation-frame').replaceWith('<div class="div-animation-frame"><embed src="tcs.swf"></div>');
})

// Clicking on the next button will swap the animation file
// Somehow not working
// Copy this to console, hit enter 
// It now works

$('.div-next-fab').on( 'click', function() {
    $('.div-animation-frame').replaceWith("<div class='div-animation-frame'><embed src='ocs.swf'></div>");
})
 });
```

Comment: Did you  add the script tags ?

Comment: change `replaceWith()` to `html()`

Comment: Yes, I did and also tried `html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Change

```
$('.div-next-fab').on( 'click', function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.div-next-fab' function() {
```

so your final code should be something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var companiesList = ['tcs', 'ocs', 'dhl', 'leopards'];
 var currentIndex = 0;

$('.button-start').on('click', function() {
  currentIndex = 0;
  $('body').append("<div class='div-next-fab'></div>");
  $('.div-next-fab').append("<i class='fas fa-arrow-right'>");
  $('.div-animation-frame').replaceWith('<div class="div-animation-frame"><embed src="'+ companiesList[currentIndex] +'.swf"></div>');
  currentIndex++;
})

// Clicking on the next button will swap the animation file
// Somehow not working
// Copy this to console, hit enter 
// It now works

$(document).on( 'click', '.div-next-fab' ,function() {
    $('.div-animation-frame').replaceWith("<div class='div-animation-frame'><embed src='"+ companiesList[currentIndex] +".swf'></div>");
    currentIndex = (currentIndex >= companiesList.length - 1) ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
})
});
```

Comment: I think I understand your point but what could the be the easy fix for this?

Comment: @MusaUsman I realized that you try to replace `'.div-animation-frame'` with element with same class so no need to change `replaceWith` to `html` you can just change the code above and everything will be ok

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" : HTML : 69

Comment: Error on line which you asked me to change

Comment: @MusaUsman you surly meant in the next line of it .. cause you changing the outer quotes  from single quotes to double quotes inside `replaceWith` .. code should work correctly now

Comment: @MusaUsman I update the answer with a little bit of code to let the code start from 0 when click `button-start` and start from 0 again when no next svg on the array